# MongoDB Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Too many text expressions

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-query

I am attempting to build a query for MongoDB in Java and I am running into this error, "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Too many text expressions" whenever I run the query.

The database is full of documents with a text property that is indexed for full text searching. I am trying to build a query to find any documents that match one or more of the queries in queryList and are within a certain time range. It works fine if there is only one query in the queryList, but fails otherwise.

Any ideas?

```
BasicDBList queryList = new BasicDBList();

for(String queryString : queryStrings)
{
    queryList.add(new BasicDBObject("$text", new BasicDBObject("$search", queryString)));
}

BasicDBObject queries = new BasicDBObject("$or", queryList);

DBObject query =  QueryBuilder.start()
    .and(endpointQuery,
         QueryBuilder.start().put("time").greaterThan(minTime).get(),
         QueryBuilder.start().put("time").lessThan(maxTime).get())
    .get();

DBCursor cursor = tweets.find(query);
```

Comment: Maybe you simply mixed them up, but I don't see that you use the `queries` object to actually perform a query, and `endpointQuery` isn't defined. Should these have the same name, or is there another part of the query?

Comment: @mnemosyn Despite the question not showing the query being executed the clear problem is MongoDB cannot execute more than one "text" or "geospatial" index expression in a single query. You cannot "mix" text or geospatial in the same query also.

Comment: @NeilLunn: In my defense, there was a bit of wine involved ;-) +1

Comment: @mnemosyn In vino veritas is always an acceptable excuse :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is pretty exact. What you are trying to do is create "multiple text queries" inside an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition. MongoDB cannot do that and it is in fact stated in the first line of [Restrictions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#restrictions) in the manual page for [**`$text`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/).

Moreover, you are not **supposed** to do that, but rather specify **one** text index on your collection to search on multiple fields if required:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "comments": "text", "title": "text" })
```

And then you probably want to assign weights [as shown here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/).

But it seems all you are really asking is to search for "multiple terms". So you don't use an `$or` for this, but just submit the list of terms separated by spaces:

```js
db.collection.find({ "$text": { "$search": "something else" } })
```

Any words in the space delimited list are then searched for within the context of whatever fields are within the text index, and any document that contains "any" of those words will be returned. With the results ordered by "weight" of more matches of the words in that list.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I skimmed right past the restrictions when I was looking at the documentation.

Comment: @thraxst Glad you learned something. Do not forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I didn't fully explain what I was doing in my question, but each 'queryString' is a space delimited list of terms that must be in the document. For instance, the queryString array would look something like [ "New York Yankees", "Boston Red Sox", "Detroit Tigers" ] and I am trying to find any documents that contain all of the terms in at least one of those strings.

Do you know if this is possible with one query without filtering the results afterwards or do I need to perform one query per 'queryString'?

Comment: @thraxst You cannot specify "phrases" in MongoDB text searches. It's really just basic. If you want anything more advanced then use a text search engine. I believe your question is answered.

Comment: @Neil I am using parse server on heroku and facing same issue, where I can apply this solution on parse server. My original question is here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014852/fulltext-is-not-working-in-parse-server-with-mlab

Comment: @KishorPatidar save your sanity and run far far away from Parse.