# fullText is not working in Parse Server with Mlab

Tags: parse-platform, mlab, parse-cloud-code

I am running `parse server(2.8.4)` on heroku with Mlab. I a trying to search based on word match but the fullText throwing an error,here is my query:

```
var query1 = new Parse.Query("SearchTerms");
query1.fullText("searchString", "programmer");
```

It throwing below error:

```
ParseError {
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421284+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 1,
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421285+00:00 app[web.1]:   message: {
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421286+00:00 app[web.1]:     name: 'MongoError',
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421287+00:00 app[web.1]:     message: 'text index required for $text query',
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421288+00:00 app[web.1]:     ok: 0,
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421289+00:00 app[web.1]:     errmsg: 'text index required for $text query',
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421290+00:00 app[web.1]:     code: 27,
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421291+00:00 app[web.1]:     codeName: 'IndexNotFound',
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421292+00:00 app[web.1]:     operationTime: '6762703032942592018',
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421293+00:00 app[web.1]:     '$clusterTime': { clusterTime: '6762703032942592018', signature: [Object] }
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421294+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2019-11-24T03:01:42.421295+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

On Web I found below solution:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   {
     field1: "text",
     field2: "text",
     etc...         
   }
)
```

But I don't know where to place this code.

Is there any way we can use this solution with `mlab`

**INDEX ISSUE HAS BEEN RESOLVED by following a guide from @Suat**

But new issue arrives:
I am using 10 or query with `fullText` and getting this error:

```
    [31merror[39m: Error generating response. ParseError {
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632775+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 1,
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632776+00:00 app[web.1]: message: MongoError: Too many text expressions
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632778+00:00 app[web.1]: at queryCallback (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:247:25)
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632779+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:531:18
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632781+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632783+00:00 app[web.1]: name: 'MongoError',
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632784+00:00 app[web.1]: message: 'Too many text expressions',
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632785+00:00 app[web.1]: ok: 0,
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632787+00:00 app[web.1]: errmsg: 'Too many text expressions',
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632788+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 2,
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632789+00:00 app[web.1]: codeName: 'BadValue',
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632791+00:00 app[web.1]: operationTime: Timestamp { bsontype: 'Timestamp', low: 6, high_: 1574671603 },
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632792+00:00 app[web.1]: '$clusterTime': { clusterTime: [Timestamp], signature: [Object] },
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632793+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
2019-11-25T08:46:46.632794+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is mostly MongoDB and mLab specificed.

1. Open your mLab dashboard
2. Select your deployment
3. Select your database
4. Select your collection

In collection detail page there are Documents, Indexes, Stats, Tools on top of page.

Choose Indexes and click to 'Add Index' button there will be a popup screen which you can enter indexes like that

```
{
     "job": "text"      
}
```

and then click 'Create In Background' button. After a few seconds your index will be created and now you can use your fullText function.

But remember

> Note: Full Text Search can be resource intensive. Ensure the cost of using indexes is worth the benefit, see storage requirements & performance costs of text indexes..

Comment: Thanks @Suat. I have created index and it is working. But and another issue arrives after this. I am adding error info in my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020211/mongodb-cant-canonicalize-query-badvalue-too-many-text-expressions If your problem has been solved in this topic please mark my answer.

Comment: Hi @Suit your answer resolved my issue is with index but the second solution is now working for me, actually I am using parse server not directly mongo so I am not aware where I need to place the solution that mentioned in the reference   question

Comment: I got you but you need to open another question for that problem. Because your new problem is not relational with question title.

Comment: Yes, I am placing a new qustion